# Docker container status not Up

Tags: docker

status: Exited (0) 3 seconds ago

command:

```
docker run -d -it -i -t --name test ubuntu sh -c "echo "Input website:"; read website; echo "Searching.."; sleep 1; curl http:\\$website;"
```

Comment: That means the command completed successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've used multiple `"` in your command with no `escape characters` or `'`. Your command should be like this:

```
docker run -d -it -i -t --name test ubuntu sh -c "echo 'Input website:'; read website; echo 'Searching..'; sleep 1; curl 'http:\\$website;'"
```

Or:

```
docker run -d -it -i -t --name test ubuntu sh -c "echo \"Input website:\"; read website; echo \"Searching..\"; sleep 1; curl 'http:\\$website;'"
```

Or if it's not working, you can change `http://` to `http:\/\/` which may help you if still it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost done it, but made mistake in

```
http:\\
```

where should be

```
http://
```

so, the string looks like:

```
docker run -it --rm --name test ubuntu sh -c "echo 'Input website:'; read website; echo 'Searching..'; sleep 1; curl http://$website;"
```

Comment: I changed to http://, still same status: Exited (0)

Comment: @jimbiz i've updated the string, seems like there's no curl in that container, try another one

Comment: @jimbiz as well you should pay attention to remove the container each time on run and remove -d due to not allowing you to interact with container

Comment: I think there is something 'cos I using windows cmd, anyway I changed ' to ", but still exited.

Comment: I found a solution, " is \"